# Do the standard library versions of alignment-unaware array-form allocation functions meet the requirements on alignment?

Tags: c++, alignment, dynamic-memory-allocation, std

The relevant paragraph is [[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#allocation-3) (emphasis mine):

> (3) For an allocation function other than a reserved placement allocation function, the pointer returned on a successful call shall represent the address of storage that is aligned as follows:
> (3.1) -- If the allocation function takes an argument of type `std​::​align_­val_­t`, the storage will have the alignment specified by the value of this argument.
> **(3.2)** -- Otherwise, if the allocation function is named `operator new[]`, the storage is aligned for any object that does not have new-extended alignment and is ***no larger than* the requested size**.
> **(3.3)** -- Otherwise, the storage is aligned for any object that does not have new-extended alignment and is ***of* the requested size**.

My understanding is as follows:

Both the single-object and the array forms of alignment-unaware allocation functions cap the guaranteed alignment to [`__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.predefined#1.7).

With that constraint, and assuming `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ == 8u`:

- The single-object form aligns for any object *of* the requested size. Thus, a request of 4 bytes would only guarantee 4-byte-aligned storage, as an 8-byte-aligned object would be at least 8 bytes in size. A 3-byte request would only guarantee 1-byte alignment, as an object with any stricter alignment could not be 3 bytes in size. (An object's size is a (non-zero) multiple of its alignment requirement (`sizeof(x) % alignof(decltype(x)) == 0`).)
- The array form aligns for any object *no larger than* the requested size. Thus, a request of 4 bytes would only guarantee 4-byte-aligned storage (as above), but a 3-byte request would guarantee *2*-byte alignment, as a 2-byte-aligned object could be only 2 bytes in size.

The array form must therefore provide stronger guarantees; it must satisfy alignment requirements for a superset of objects for which the single-object form must satisfy such requirements. In other words, the post-conditions of the former subsume (and strengthen) those of the latter. Yet, the default behavior of the standard library version of the array form is to simply forward to the corresponding single-object form and return its result. Would that not mean that `::operator new[](3)`, being equivalent (by default) to `::operator new(3)`, yields a pointer to storage only guaranteed to have 1-byte alignment, failing the above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have proven that single element operator new provided by the standard library must allocate memory more aligned than the requirement for single element allocators in general.

That seems plausible.

Those restrictions are the minimum requirements for any allocation function in C++, including ones a programmer writes.

It turns out, if your logic is right, that the base operator new has to return 2 byte aligned memory when asked for 3 bytes.

But when you write your own you have to only follow those rules.

Comment: So, if I wrote a bare-minimum implementation of `operator new(size_t)` (one that would align to only 1 byte on a 3-byte request) to replace the library version, wouldn't I also have to replace `operator new[](size_t)`? Otherwise, the library version would just use my replacement `operator new` and would fail to satisfy the array-form alignment requirements!

Comment: Also, reading over [\[new.delete\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete): [new.delete.general] doesn't seem to mention the array forms; [new.delete.single]/3 doesn't say anything about satisfying any stronger alignment requirements than are mandated by [\[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation\]/3.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#allocation-3.3), implying that only those requirements are binding on any replacements; [new.delete.array]/3 explicitly states that the requirements on library `operator new[](size_t)` are the "same as for the corresponding single-object forms".